# different formatting for EURO in JODA and JAVA

Tags: java, price, joda-money

The below code (which is in JODA) prints: **€12,23**

```
String formatAmount = new MoneyFormatterBuilder().
               appendCurrencySymbolLocalized().
               appendAmountLocalized().
               toFormatter().
               withLocale(new Locale("es", "ES")).
               print(Money.of(CurrencyUnit.EUR, 12.23));

System.out.print(formatAmount);
```

The below code prints: **12,23 €**

```
String formatAmount = NumberFormat.
             getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("es", "ES")).
             format(amount);

System.out.print(formatAmount);
```

Can someone tell me which one is correct and why both the libraries print differently?

Comment: It's just a matter of format, there are no correct or incorrect ways. Just Joda and Java decided to do it differently.

Comment: @dabadaba But in spanish locale the correct way of formatting the currency is 12,23 € , correct?